# MD5 Brute Force Algorithm

Tags: objective-c

I am coding an Objective-C MD5 hash "decrypter". Since you cannot decrypt such a hash function, I am approaching it with a brute force algorithm, that tries every single password combination until it found the correct one or not.

I would highly appreciate any help to improve the algorithm to make it even faster. I am currently computing approx. 28,000 guesses per second on my iMac and 7,000 on an iPhone 6. I know that 7,000 guesses are quite ridiculous compared to the performance a tool like [hashcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcat) has (2.2 billion guesses per second on my iMac), nonetheless I want a mobile MD5 decryption tool on my iPhone.

```
-(void)brute_sequentialWithMaxLength:(int)length
{
   iterateFurther = YES;

   char * buf = malloc(length + 1);

   for (int i=1; i <= length; i++)
   {
     memset(buf, 0, length+1);
     [self brute_implWithChar:buf andIndex:0 andDepth:i];
   }

  free(buf);
}



-(void)brute_implWithChar:(char*)str andIndex:(int)index andDepth:(int)max_depth
{ 

 for (int i=0; i < [pm_maskArray count] && iterateFurther == YES;i++)
 {
    alph = [[pm_maskArray objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:0];

    str[index] = alph;

    if (index == max_depth - 1)
    {

         if ([[self makeMD5StringFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",str]] isEqualToString:pm_hashString])
         {
           NSLog(@"Found");
           iterateFurther = NO;
         }


    }
    else
    {
      [self brute_implWithChar:str andIndex:index+1 andDepth:max_depth];
    }

 }   
}
```

Answer (score 6):

rolfl's answer pretty well explains why this isn't really a realistically reasonable approach to cracking passwords.  I'm going to set that answer aside, ignore it, and address some of the specific ways in which this code could be improved if it were part of a more realistic program.

As a start, this code has one massive, massive problem: What happens when we actually find a match?

```
NSLog("Found");
```

And that's it.

We don't log the password.  We don't post a notification, return it, tell a delegate.  We don't save it as a local variable.  We just post a borderline useless log statement claiming we found it.

And what's worse?  WE KEEP CALCULATING!

We're done with this call to `brute_implWithChar`, but as soon as it returns, the loop in `brute_sequentialWithMaxLength:` is on another iteration and we jump right back in `brute_implWithChar...`, and go through all of that, and then return and do it all again, etc.

This is a major problem which should be addressed.

---

We can speed this up by using fast enumeration in `brute_implWithChar...`

But to do that, let's first talk about: `pm_maskArray`.  You don't show this anywhere, but I can only assume it's an array of `NSString` objects.  I'm going to recommend instead that we use an array of `NSNumber` objects.

And why `NSNumber`?  Because `NSNumber` can also hold characters:

```
NSNumber *theCapitalLetterC = @'C';
char theCStyleCapicalCChar = [theCapitalLetterC characterValue];
```

So... presuming we've built `pm_maskArray` into an appropriate array of `NSNumber` objects, our loop is now going to look something more like this:

```
for (NSNumber *aChar in pm_maskArray) {
    char alph = [aChar characterValue];

    // all your checking stuff
    // when/if a match is found, we can:
    break;
    // to stop the loop and return executing at the first line after the loop
    // or in this case we can also:
    return;
    // to exit the method entirely.
}
```

As it stands, this `forin` loop will already allow you SEVERAL more guesses per second, as it will send a message to the `pm_maskArray` about once for every 16 times your version of the code was sending the message (approximately).

And looking back to my first point, we probably want to change this method to return an `NSString` object, rather than `void`.  Then, if we find a match, we return it, otherwise, we return `nil`.

I'm also going to rename this method to strip the "and"s out of it, as they're inappropriate.

So if our method looks like this:

```
-(NSString *)brute_implWithChar:(char*)str index:(int)index depth:(int)depth
// returns matching password or nil
```

Then the loop in which we call it can look like this:

```
NSString *crackedPassword = nil;
while ((crackedPassword = [self brute_implWithChar:but index:0 depth:i]) == nil 
    && i <= length) {
    ++i;
}
return crackedPassword;
```

Now, on every unsuccessful call of `brute_implWithChar:index:depth:` for which we don't find a password, `nil` is returned and assigned to `crackedPassword`.  If `crackedPassword == nil` evaluates to true AND `i` is still not larger than `length`, the loop will iterate again.

Meanwhile, the loop will stop iterating as soon as `crackedPassword` evaluates to anything non-`nil`.  And since we're returning the password from the inner method, the outer method can return it to its caller as well.  If the password isn't found before `i <= length` evaluates false, then `nil` will be returned, indicating that the password wasn't found--otherwise, the password is returned.

Comment: I actually left out some parts of the code. I do stop it using the iterateFurther==YES check in the for loop. 
Thank you nevertheless for your effort, I'm going to test this out.

Comment: That doesn't completely stop it though.

Answer (score 4):

Your expectations are unrealistic. It is not reasonable, with current mobile technology, to brute force a password in any realistic time frame. There are three factors that you should know here, though...

1. even at 2.2-billion passwords per second, you will take years on average to 'crack' a single password. There are about \$3.4 \times 10^{39}\$ possible MD5 hashes, and you are looking for a collision in that space, at 2.2 billion (make it 3.4 billion)  per second, it will take \$10^{30}\$ seconds to do them all, or about half that time to get one on average..... I believe that's about \$10^{22}\$ centuries.... billions of times older than the universe.... Obviously, you don't need to solve all MD5 collisions, just those that relate to typical password lengths, but, a 'strong' 8 char password (using upper, lower, digits, and special chars) will take on average \$10^5\$ seconds at 10 billion per second.
2. current MD5 attack vectors rely on generating collisions for an existing hash, and there are ways that the algorithm for MD5 can be exploited to help identify the the colliding hash in a way that's more deterministic than brute force. Using various technologies and complex algorithms, it's possible to compute a colliding hash in the timeframe of hours, on various existing computers. These attacks are not brute-force, but complex calculations.
3. Most password systems use a 'salt' to create essentially a two-factor password, and these salted passwords are harder to 'brute force', because, even if you know a collision for the resulting MD5 sum, you need to know the salt as well to 'unlock' the result.

Still, the most reliable way to break the MD5 algorithm (assuming an unsalted password), is to [use rainbow tables](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rainbow-hash-cracking/). These rainbow tables are databases of MD5 values, and the input texts that produce those MD5s. In other words, it is a reverse-lookup for a password. Rainbow tables answer the question "what password would create the MD5 abcxxx...xxx?" Various groups of people have published rainbow tables, and you can search for them. Typical tables are based on calculating the MD5 sum for common passwords. They are typically a few hundred gigabytes in size. Remember, there are far fewer 'typical' passwords than there are possible MD5 sums.... It has taken many people a number of years to build these tables, so you are leveraging the work of others to help solve your problems.

Some of the tables are available as web-services. In other words, you can just query an online database for common passwords that produce a specific MD5 sum.

If the tables are comprehensive enough (have the right coverage of typical passwords), it is typically reasonable to expect a solution in a few seconds or so.

**Note:** after reading up on hashcat, it is apparent that it is not a brute-force tool, it is a calculation algorithm that exploits weaknesses in MD5. Additionally, it can also leverage the performance capabilities of GPU accelerators. While 28,000 brute-force calculations per second is not great, the 2.2billion reported by hashcat is not an apples-to-apples comparison.

Comment: A few hundred GB database won't fit on a mobile device either...

Comment: Remember that 10^5 seconds is a day. Slow, but not completely out of bounds, especially if you could pause and continue the work. Also, generally if you have the MD5 you have the salt. Salts are only really intended to beat rainbow tables.

Comment: @nhgrif - true, which is why I suggested using a web-service that's already there.

Comment: @raptortech97 - you are correct, it is a day, at 10Billion per second, but the 'big' computer and algorithm only does 2.2, and the current code does 0.000028 and the mobile does 0.000007 billion per second....